# Why doesn't my word counting binary tree program work correctly?

Tags: c, binary-tree

My program takes read input through getchar(), saves the number of appearances of each word using a binary tree structure and then prints them at the end. Any set of non-blank characters that only contains digits, underscore and letters and doesn't start with a digit counts as a word.
When I put the line `First_word First_word First_word Second_word Third_word Forth_word` in a file called `file.input` and run the program through the command `./a.out <file.input` this is the output I get:    `3    First_word` Whereas there should've been other words as well.

I've tested them and `getword` and `print` work correctly. This is the code I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct bt_node {
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct bt_node *left;
    struct bt_node *right;
};


int main()
{
    extern struct bt_node *first;
    int getword(char *, int);
    struct bt_node *search(char *word, struct bt_node *node), *node = NULL;
    void print(struct bt_node *node);

    int lim = 100;
    char word[lim];

    while (getword(word, lim) != EOF) {
        if (!(isalpha(word[0]) || word[0] == '_'))
            continue;
        search(word, node)->count++;
        node = first;
    }
    
    print(first);

    return 0;
}

void print(struct bt_node *node)
{
    if (node->left != NULL)
        print(node->left);
    printf("%4d\t%s\n", node->count, node->word);
    if (node->right != NULL)
        print(node->right);
}

struct bt_node *search(char *word, struct bt_node *node)
{
    struct bt_node *generate_node(char *word);
    if (node == NULL)
        node = generate_node(word);

    int comp = strcmp(word, node->word);
    if (comp == 0)
        return node;
    else
        return search(word, 0 < comp ? node->right : node->left);
}

int getword(char *word, int lim)
{
    int c, temp, getch(void);
    void ungetch(int);
    char *w = word;

    pass_space: /* if encountered a comment or string skip it and go back to this step */
    while (isspace(c = getch()))
        ;
    if (c == '/') {
        if ((temp = getch()) == '*') { 
            while ((c = getch()) != EOF)
                if (c == '*' && (c = getch()) == '/')
                    goto pass_space;
                else if (c == '*')
                    ungetch(c);
        } else
            ungetch(temp);
    } else if (c == '\"') {
        while ((c = getch()) != EOF)
            if (c == '\"')
                goto pass_space;
    }
    if (c != EOF)
        *w++ = c;
    if (!isalpha(c) && c != '_') {
        *w = '\0';
        return c;
    }
    for ( ; --lim > 0; w++)
        if (!isalnum(*w = getch()) && *w != '_') {
            ungetch(*w);
            break;
        }
    *w = '\0';
    return word[0];
}

#define BUFSIZE 100

int buf[BUFSIZE];
char bufp = 0;

int getch(void)
{
    return bufp > 0 ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c)
{
    if (bufp < BUFSIZE)
        buf[bufp++] = c;
    else
        printf("ungetch: too many characters, didn't unread %c\n", c);
}

struct bt_node *generate_node(char *word)
{
    struct bt_node *bt_alloc(void);
    char *alloc_char(int);
    
    struct bt_node *node = bt_alloc();
    node->word = alloc_char(strlen(word)+1);
    strcpy(node->word, word);
    node->count = 0;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;

    return node;
}

#define BTALLOCSIZE 10000

static struct bt_node bt_allocbuf[BTALLOCSIZE];
static struct bt_node *bt_allocp = bt_allocbuf;

struct bt_node *first = bt_allocbuf;

struct bt_node *bt_alloc(void)
{
    if (bt_allocp <= bt_allocbuf + BTALLOCSIZE)
        return bt_allocp++;
    else {
        printf("bt_alloc - error: can't allocate\n");
        return NULL;
    }
}

#define ALLOCSIZE 10000

static char char_allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE];
static char  *char_allocp = char_allocbuf;

char *alloc_char(int n)
{
    if (char_allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - char_allocp >= n) {
        char_allocp += n;
        return char_allocp - n;
    } else {
        printf("alloc_char - error: can't allocate\n");
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you show isn't a [mre]. For one reason it won't even build.

Comment: _My program takes a file as an input_ : I don't see that it does. It doesn't take any parameters. It just processes standard input. Of course the caller can redirect stdin to a file.

Comment: As for your problem, my suggestion is that you start over, *from scratch* with an empty `main` function. Build with extra warning enabled, treated as errors. Only when it builds cleanly you test it. Only when all tests pass you continue to add a ***very small*** bit of code. Build and test like before. Don't add more until it builds and passes all tests. This way it will become *much* easier to isolate problems and to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) only the relevant parts.

Comment: And what is your actual assignment? Why do you have your own memory buffer and allocation system? What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: Furthermore, you are missing come crucial error checking from your allocation functions. Considering that the memory allocation buffer is rather small, what happens if you run out of space, and the allocation functions return a null pointer? I don't see you check for that anywhere?

Comment: @user1934428
Sorry for inconvenience, but that's how the book I use refers to reading input through getchar().

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I edited and put the whole code.

Comment: While I'm basically opposed against burning books, I feel that there are some books where I would make an exception ......

Comment: Putting the whole code is too much. Try to strip down the code to a minimal reprodcible example, but together with example input data.

Comment: The line `struct bt_node *search(char *word, struct bt_node *node), *node = NULL;` is *highly* confusing. As a general advice, one declaration per line. And declaring functions inside functions is also rather unusual.

Comment: I'm confused. Put all words into a histogram and print them out at the end. How do you use a binary tree?

Comment: @Neil What’s a histogram??? It was the exercise in the book, count how many times does each word in input appears, and then at the end print each word with their appearance count beside them. Binary trees would be faster than other ways such as say, a linear search through an array, if the order words appear in is random according to the book.

Comment: What if they are in order? I think your binary tree is now a linked-list. A histogram counts the number of equal elements. You might implement this as a [hash map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) between a word and a positive number.

Comment: I implemented this; it is fairly hard to get the right behaviour from all input. Recommend setting limits on how long the input is and what it contains first and working on your algorithm first.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, the problem was that in this function:

```
struct bt_node *search(char *word, struct bt_node *node)
{
    struct bt_node *generate_node(char *word);
    if (node == NULL)
        node = generate_node(word);

    int comp = strcmp(word, node->word);
    if (comp == 0)
        return node;
    else
        return search(word, 0 < comp ? node->right : node->left);
}
```

I were assigning the pointer `generate_node` returned into the variable `node`, thinking that it'll assign the pointer to node->left or node->right, because of pass-by-value. As a result, structures were generated and saved but their address wasn't assigned to child node pointers and `node->left` and `node->right` stayed `NULL`. Changing the function this way helped:

```
struct bt_node *search(char *word, struct bt_node **node_pt)
{
    struct bt_node *generate_node(char *word);
    
    if (*node_pt == NULL)
        *node_pt = generate_node(word);

    int comp = strcmp(word, (*node_pt)->word);
    if (comp == 0)
        return *node_pt;
    else
        return search(word, (0 < comp ? &(*node_pt)->right : &(*node_pt)->left));
}
```

And now I just have to modify the function declaration so that it corresponds to the new definition and also change the call `search(word, node)->count++;` in main into `search(word, &node)->count++;`

Comment: Any particular reason you put your function prototypes (forward declarations) inside `main()`. That's is a bit wonky. Why not `int bufp = 0;` to avoid the array subscript warning?